# Factorizing code in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a set of Cloud Functions, to provide an API to access data in one of my Firebase projects.

First, below are some working functions I have set to allow a client to access a few collections.
(Complete code for the *index.ts* file)

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as cors from "cors";

const corsHandler = cors();

admin.initializeApp();


exports.getTypeOne = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {
  resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");

  corsHandler(req, resp, async () => {
    const refStr = "TopCollection/TypeOne";
    const dbRef = admin.database().ref(refStr);

    if (dbRef === undefined) {
      resp.send({});
      return;
    }

    dbRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      const snpsv = snapshot.val();

      if ((snpsv === undefined) || (snpsv == null)) {
        resp.send({});
        return;
      }

      // At this point we have: (snpsv !== undefined) && (snpsv != null)

      resp.send(snpsv);
    });
  }); // End corsHandler.
});


exports.getTypeTwo = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {
  .... code similar to getTypeOne ....
    ... except for the next line ....
    const refStr = "TopCollection/TypeTwo";
  .... code similar to getTypeOne ....
});
```

The code above works as I expect, but from now on I need to set more functions:

*exports.getTypeThree*, *exports.getTypeFour*, *exports.getTypeFive* ... up to *exports.getTypeTwenty*.
Obviously that is going to be a lot of repeated code, since all the functions will be very much alike.

As a consequence of this situation I have tried to factorize the code, but for some reason it is not working.
Any relevant help would be very welcome. Below is what I have tried at this point. The code is compiling without any problem:

```
const getDBData = (req:functions.https.Request,
    resp:functions.Response,
    type:string) => {
  resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");

  corsHandler(req, resp, async () => {
    const refStr = "TopCollection/" + type;
    const dbRef = admin.database().ref(refStr);

    if (dbRef === undefined) {
      resp.send({});
      return;
    }

    dbRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      const snpsv = snapshot.val();

      if ((snpsv === undefined) || (snpsv == null)) {
        resp.send({});
        return;
      }

      // At this point we have: (snpsv !== undefined) && (snpsv != null)

      resp.send(snpsv);
    });
  }); // End corsHandler.
};


exports.getTypeThree = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {
  getDBData(req, resp, "TypeThree");
});


exports.getTypeFour = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {
  getDBData(req, resp, "TypeFour");
});


... etc ...
```

Here is what shows up in the Web Developer Tools Console of my browser:

```
GEThttps://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/getTypeThree
[HTTP/3 403 Forbidden 272ms]

This page is in Quirks Mode. Page layout may be impacted. For Standards Mode use “<!DOCTYPE html>”.
```